# how to count data with group by

Tags: mysql

I have table `customer_survey`

```
     User_id | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3
      1           GOOD          BAD          WORST
      2           GOOD          GOOD         GOOD
      3           WORST         GOOD         WORST
      4           BAD           BAD          BAD
      5           BAD           GOOD         GOOD
      6           GOOD          BAD          GOOD
      7           GOOD          BEST         GOOD
      8           GOOD          WORST        GOOD
```

and I have table `score`

```
      Id    description
      1      WORST
      2      BAD
      3      GOOD 
      4      BEST
```

RESULT :

```
               WORST     BAD   GOOD    BEST
 Question 1      1         2     5       0
 Question 2      1         3     3       1 
 Question 3      1         1     5       0
```

I am confused for this.

Comment: 1. See normalization. 2. Once normalized, why would you want to view the result in MySQL?

Comment: i wanna rank a question by user answer , i ll see about normalization . Thanx GhitaB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy but troublesome method:

```
SELECT
'Question 1' AS QUESTION,
COUNT(CASE customer_survey.question1 WHEN 'WORST' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS WORST
FROM
customer_survey
UNION ALL
(SELECT
'Question 2' AS QUESTION,
COUNT(CASE customer_survey.question2 WHEN 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS GOOD
FROM
customer_survey)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
'Question 3' AS QUESTION,
COUNT(CASE customer_survey.question3 WHEN 'BAD' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS BAD
FROM
customer_survey)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
'Question 4' AS QUESTION,
COUNT(CASE customer_survey.question4 WHEN 'BEST' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS BEST
FROM
customer_survey)
```

Comment: Awesome but troublesome , Thanks @phsaires